# 'www' - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, header, request

```
Font from origin 'http://test.ru' has been blocked from loading by 
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://www.test.ru' is therefore not allowed access
```

есть сайт `test.ru`, если зайти туда так - `www.test.ru` скрипты, шрифты, ничего не подключается, подскажите как с этим справиться?

Comment: Прочитать про политики безопасности браузера(Access-Control-Allow-Origin) и как их настраивать на сервере(отправка специального заголовка).

Comment: сервер тут не причем... `www.test.ru` и `test.ru` - считает разными доменами.. как это исправить?

Comment: Никак, потому что это априори разные домены [wiki: www prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web#WWW_prefix). Поэтому вопрос стоит только так: как заставить сервер не делать различий для двух доменов, один с www и второй без.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте редирект 301 через htaccess и забудьте про второй домен!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.ru$
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```